# MongoDB findAndModify not working with monk

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, monk

I am trying to use `findAndModify` with the node.js mongodb module `monk`.This is the method that I am using,this throws a `500` error in my `cmd`:

```
  notesCollection.findAndModify({_id:_id},[],{_id:_id,title:title,content:content},{'new':true,'upsert':true},function(err,doc){
    if(err)
        console.error(err);
    else
    {
        console.log("Find and modify successfull");
        console.dir(doc);
    }   
});
```

[I obtained the method signature here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html).I get an error that looks like this and is uninformative:

```
 POST /notes/edit/542bdec5712c0dc426d41342 500 86ms - 1.35kb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monk implements methods that are more in line with the shell syntax for method signatures than what is provided by the node native driver. So in this case the "shell" documentation for [`.findAndModify()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) is more appropriate for here:

```
  notescollection.findAndModify(
      {
        "query": { "_id": id },
        "update": { "$set": { 
            "title": title,
            "content": content
        }},
        "options": { "new": true, "upsert": true }
      },
      function(err,doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log( doc );
      }
);
```

Also noting that you should be using the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator or posibly even the [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) operator where you only want fields applied when the document is created. When operators like this a re **not** applied then the *"whole"* document is replaced with whatever content you specify for the "update".

You also don't need to supply the "_id" field in the update section, as even when an "upsert" occurs, anything present in the "query" portion of the statement is implied to be created in a new document.

The monk documentation also hints at the correct syntax to use for the [method signature](https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk#and-modify).

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Had the same problem, and even though I liked it, the accepted answer didn't work for me.</sub>

It's not clear enough, but the documentation hints at the correct syntax, starting with the [signatures](https://github.com/Automattic/monk#signatures):

> - All commands accept the simple `data[, …], fn`. For example
>
>   - `findAndModify({}, {}, fn)`

And from the [finding section](https://github.com/Automattic/monk#and-modify):

> `users.findAndModify({ _id: '' }, { $set: {} });`

Finally, continuing with the signatures section:

> - You can pass options in the middle: `data[, …], options, fn`

Putting it all together:

```
collection.findAndModify({
    _id: '',
}, {
    $set: {
        value: '',
    },
}, {
    upsert: true,
});
```

So in this case, `data[, …]` is the couple `{}, {}` objects: query and update. Then you can add the callback as a 4th parameter in my snippet.